# Cannot Assign Type to Resolved Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have the below code that when I try to replace 'any' with 'ResponseType', I get the error

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(result: ResponseType) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.   Types of parameters 'result' and 'value' are incompatible.     Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'.
```

Code

```
interface ResponseType = {
    foo: string,
    bar: string
}

  makeExternalRequest(param).
    then((result : any) => {
      const data = processData(result);
      res.status(200).json(data });
    }).catch((error) => {
      const errorDetails = getErrorStatusAndMessage(error);
      res.status(errorDetails.status).json({ message: errorDetails.message });
    });

const makeExternalRequest = (param) => {
  return got(
    `https://somewebsite.com/${param}`,
  ).json();
};
```

Why is typescript throwing this error? The promise should be resolved and this type should be the response type for a non error case.

Comment: Which npm packages are you using for your HTTP requests? because never see `got` as a function? you mean `get`?

Comment: Typescript os throwing this error because the types are not compatível. Please, provide the return types of makeEsternalRequest and the methods got and json inside It.

Comment: I'm using the npm `got` package

Comment: Your code uses `(result : any) => …` but the error message says "*type `(result: ResponseType) => void`*"? Please show us your actual code.

Comment: "*this type should be the response type*" - but `got` doesn't know about that, you haven't told it. It returns `unknown` by default, and TypeScript rightly complains that you're not checking the value of the JSON.